# Eclipse - Jasper report not compiling (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester)

Tags: java, eclipse, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate a jasper report via the Eclipse ide, however when I execute the following line of code:

```
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("reports/samplereport.jrxml");
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:146)
```

I have added the apache common digester jar as a project library but it does not seem to make a difference.
NOTE: I am from a java novice (i.e. Ive a .NET background,) so I am very likely doing something really obvious!

Comment: you should be missing some jars. could you post your jars list ?

Comment: jasperreports3.7.6.jar, commons-digester3-3.2.jar, JRE System Library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you may be missing some jars. try to add these ones with any version.

jasperreports-.jar;
jasperreports-javaflow.jar;
commons-beanutils.jar;
commons-collections.jar;
commons-logging.jar;
commons-digester.jar

Comment: I was adding the wrong library. I had downloaded the apache commons digester jar separately v 3.3.2, however when I when into the jasper engine plugin folder, an apache commons digester library v1.7 existed, I added this and it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: @bstack Thanks..I was having the same problem. I got the error when I was using v3 but using v1.7 resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is based on maven, you can add Jasper reports as a maven dependency, see sample code snippet below. Jasper report would automatically import all the libraries it needs to work properly.

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>            
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.1</version>
</dependency>
...
```